# Long type in C# Programmed COM Object Shows as Unsupported Variant Type in VB6

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6

I have a DLL programmed in C# which I am converting into a COM object for use in a VB6 application.  Have have several methods and properties defined as `long` type which, when accessed in VB6, end up showing as "Unsupported variant type."  Then I noticed that a function which is defined in C# as:

```
void Load(long firstNumber, int firstCheckDigit, long lastNumber , int lastCheckDigit)
```

Shows in my VB6 Object Browser as:

```
Sub Load(firstNumber As <Unsupported variant type>, firstCheckDigit As Long, lastNumber As <Unsupported variant type>, lastCheckDigit As Long)
```

Obviously, something about this conversion is turning the C# `int` type into a VB6 `Long` type which isn't a problem for me.  However, I do need the `firstNumber` and `lastNumber` variables to be `long` both in C# and VB6.  The variables on the backend cannot be `int` because of the size of some values being entered.  Is there any way to do this?  Or is a long type from the DLL side incompatible with COM objects?

Comment: `Int` means different things in .NET (32bit) and VB6 (16bit). So C#'s Int becomes VB6 Long (which *is* 32bit). There's no analogue for .NET `Long` (64bit) in VB6 - do you really need this precision?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter You should provide some backing documentation in an answer :). You'd have my upvote.

Comment: @DavidL It's out there :) E.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06bkb8w2.aspx *Interop Considerations. If you are interfacing with components not written for the .NET Framework, for example Automation or COM objects, remember that Integer has a different data width (16 bits) in other environments. If you are passing a 16-bit argument to such a component, declare it as Short instead of Integer in your new Visual Basic code.* That's VB.NET, but it's the same. If OP'd like I will post this as an answer

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I actually do. These numbers are (potentially) 10-digit numbers so I've had overflows before where I'm using too large of a 10 digit number (north of the approx. 2 billion limit)

Comment: Can you pass those as strings?

Comment: That's something that I came up with.  I was hoping not to have to reverse engineer too much of this but, unfortunately, that sounds like the solution to my specific problem.

Post your first comment and the string idea as a solution and I'll be sure to dap you up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's accurate, VB6 doesn't have a 64-bit integer type.

You'll need to accommodate it with *int* or *double*.  The latter is unpleasant of course but you do get 15 digits out of it.

Comment: I think that `Currency` and `DECIMAL` can work also.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28VS.60%29.aspx <-- VB6 Datatypes

http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/data-types.php <-- c# data types

References for the future. :)